# Convergence in NIntegrate vs Integrate

Tags: numerical-integration, calculus-and-analysis

I am faced with this situation that for a certain integration, $\int _0 ^\infty \frac { \tanh (\pi \sqrt{x} )} {\sqrt{x+10} } dx$ - the command `Integrate` returns that this doesn't converge but `NIntegrate` gives back a number - but after some messages about slow convergence and precision etc.

What exactly is going on? What is the "right" answer?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Every integral over a function behaving asymptotically (when $x$ goes to infinity)  as $\frac{1}{x^\alpha}$ where $\alpha \leq1$ is divergent, it's a mathematical theorem which could be found in every reasonable handbook of calculus.
Since `Tanh[ π Sqrt[x]]` goes to one rapidly we find that the integral is indeed **divergent**.
We can demonstrate this fact with the function at hand in many ways, let's provide two of them.

### 1. using `SumConvergence`

### 2. estimating $\int _0 ^a \frac { \tanh (\pi \sqrt{x} )} {\sqrt{x+10} } dx$

### Ad.1

The integral can be easily bounded by a diverging sum

```
SumConvergence[ Tanh[ π Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x + 10], x]
```

> ```
>  False
> ```

```
Plot[ Tanh[ π Sqrt[#]]/Sqrt[# + 10]& /@ {x, IntegerPart[x + 1] - 1, 1 + IntegerPart[x]},
      {x, 0, 12}, 
      PlotRange -> {0.2, 0.31}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Filling -> {1 -> {2}},
      FillingStyle -> Darker @ Cyan, Evaluated -> True, Exclusions -> None, 
      PlotStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

### Ad.2

Let's consider a simple function `1/ Sqrt[x + 11]`:

```
Resolve[
  ForAll[x, x > 1, Tanh[ π Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x + 10] > 1/ Sqrt[x + 11]], x, Reals]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

```
Integrate[ 1/Sqrt[x + 11], {x, 0, a}, Assumptions -> a > 0]

Limit[ %, a -> ∞]
```

> ```
> -2 Sqrt[11] + 2 Sqrt[11 + a]
>
> ∞
> ```

Moreover defining

```
f[a_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[ Tanh[ π Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x + 10], {x, 0, a}] - 
                  NIntegrate[ 1/Sqrt[x + 11], {x, 0, a}]
```

we find that

```
FindRoot[ f[a], {a, 2}]
```

> ```
> {a -> 2.02636}
> ```

thus for `a > 2.02636` `NIntegrate[ Tanh[ π Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x + 10], {x, 0, a}]` exceeds `NIntegrate[ 1/Sqrt[x + 11], {x, 0, a}]`

```
Plot[{ Tanh[  π Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x + 10], 1/ Sqrt[x + 11]}, {x, 0, 15}, 
      PlotRange -> {0, 0.33}, PlotStyle -> Thick, Evaluated -> True, 
      Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

We found a simpler function with an integral smaller for an every finite parameter `a > 3` which is clearly divergent, so the original function is **divergent** as well when `a` tends to infinity.

On the other hand `NIntegrate` returns a well defined approximation with another asymptotic behaviour, this integrand `Tanh[ π Sqrt[x]]/(1 + x)^c` for every `c > 1`  provides a **convergent** integral, e.g.:

```
NIntegrate[ Tanh[ π Sqrt[x]]/(1 + x)^(5/4), {x, 0, ∞}]
```

> ```
> 3.92916
> ```

while `Integrate` is unable to provide an exact symbolic result.

The reason that *Mathematica* does return some number is that `NIntegrate` might be even better, however it returns quite clear warning:

```
NIntegrate[ Tanh[ π Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x + 10], {x, 0, ∞}]
```

> ```
> NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; 
> suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0,
> highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small. >>
>
> NIntegrate::ncvb: NIntegrate failed to converge to prescribed accuracy after 
> 9 recursive bisections in x near {x} = {8.16907*10^224}. NIntegrate obtained
> 3.843941796202754`15.954589770191005*^13977 
> and 3.843941796202754`15.954589770191005*^13977 for the integral and error estimates. >>
>
> 3.843941796202754*10^13977
> ```

Therefore one shouldn't be misled with that number. `Integrate` works fine yielding an unevaluated input:

```
Integrate[ Tanh[ π Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x + 10], {x, 0, ∞}]
```

> ```
> Integrate::idiv: 
> Integral of Tanh[ π Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[10+x] does not converge on {0, ∞}. >>
>
> Integrate[ Tanh[ π Sqrt[x]]/Sqrt[x + 10], {x, 0, ∞}]
> ```

Comment: I think you mean \alpha>-1?

Comment: No I meant that $\int_b^\infty \frac{d x}{x^\alpha}$ is divergent for $\alpha \leq 1$ and $b > 0$.

Comment: Ah, yes, was forgetting you had it in a denominator.